# Comma in "Hello Michael"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should comma be used in sentences like *"Hello, Michael"* / *"Hello Michael"* ?

For example, there is a wikipedia article [Hello, sailor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Sailor) (with comma), but it mentions two different books, a band, and two albums, all called *"Hello Sailor"* without a comma.  The [article in Grammar-Monster.com](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/comma_with_dear_hello_and_hi.htm) seems to suggest a comma, but it is not clear from the text whether it is necessary if "Hello (comma?) Michael" is a complete sentence.

Comment: Should one remove the comma from "Let's eat, grandma"?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely optional and down to personal style. Would you take a breath between the words?

Consider the difference between:

"Yes, sir" - as might be said by a shopkeeper rapidly losing patience with his customer; and

"Yes sir" - as might be said by an enthusiastic pupil.

(There's also the somewhat unique "Yessir", barked by military personnel.)

In a longer sentence, there would always be a comma before "Michael" at the end, such as: "Do you think it will rain today, Michael?"

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case - Yes, you need to use a comma between the person's name and the greeting, though in many many cases not using the comma is also allowed =)